# how to count total number of words in a file?

Tags: text-processing, wc

I am looking for a command to count number of all words in a file. For instance if a file is like this,

```
today is a 
good day
```

then it should print `5`, since there are `5` words there.

Comment: Have you tried `wc -w $FILE` ?

Comment: [Don't solve what's been solved.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746969/1273830)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The command `wc` aka. word count can do it:

```
$ wc -w <file>
```

#### example

```
$ cat sample.txt
today is a 
good day


$ wc -w sample.txt
5 sample.txt


# just the number (thanks to Stephane Chazelas' comment)
$ wc -w < sample.txt
5
```

Comment: Note that _words_ for `wc -w` don't have the same definition as for GNU `grep -w`. For `wc` a word is a sequence of one or more non-space characters (`[:space:]` character class in the current locale). For instance `foo,bar` and `foo bar` (with a non-breaking space) are each _one_ word.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this for JUST the number:

```
wc -w [file] | cut -d' ' -f1

5
```

I also like the `wc -w < [file]` approach

Finally, for storing just the word count in a variable, you could use the following:

```
myVar=($(wc -w /path/to/file))
```

This lets you skip the filename elegantly.

Comment: `wc -w < "$file"` for JUST the number.

Answer (score 3):

The better solution is using Perl:

```
perl -nle '$word += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_)); END{print $word}' filename
```

**@Bernhard**

You can check the source code of `wc` command from coreutils, I test in my machine, with file `subst.c` in bash 4.2 source.

```
time wc -w subst.c

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
```

And

```
time perl -nle '$word += scalar(split(" ", $_)); END{print $word}' subst.c

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The bigger the file is, the more efficient Perl is with respect to `wc`.

Comment: Why is this better than wc?

Comment: `wc` need open entire file before it processes, it will cause problem when you work with large file.

Comment: @Gnouc I'll upvote if you show proof

Comment: @Sparr for one thing because, to my very great surprise, it seems to be _much_ faster. I tried it on a text file with 141813504 words and `wc` took ~14sec while Perl took ~5sec!

Comment: @Gnouc I don't think that is true, I routinely use `wc` on text files of a few GB in size and have no problems.

Comment: I think the 'bigger' issue really is an answer that has a dependency on Perl and I'm never a big fan of such a dependency.  If the question was about performance that would be another thing.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant is there any chance of ever finding a *nix machine without Perl?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't know what the prevalence of Perl will be in 2 or 3 years or if a version of Perl will come up with a simple but important syntax change for simple commands or.... basically I don't know what the future will bring so I try to avoid dependencies.  I well remember the "but 98% of people use Internet Explorer, why do you care about details that affect other browsers?" era when I was building the foundation of products that were intended to work a couple of years later.

Comment: @terdon: I think problem only occurs when you don't have enough memory for file with GB size.

Comment: It used to be the case that literally no Solaris machine included Perl. Any solution that requires a programming language such as Python, Perl, or Ruby should be taken with a grain of salt, that it might *not* be there.

Comment: @Gnouc using `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.13` I could run `wc -w` on a 11GB text file on my laptop (8G RAM) with no problem, and no discernible spike in memory usage. It probably uses tmp files and not RAM.

Comment: Note that _a `split` on `/\s+/` is like a `split(' ')` except that any leading whitespace produces a null first field. That difference will give you one extra word (the null first field, that is) per line_ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6063805/1601027). So use `(split(" ", $_))` otherwise for a file created like this: `echo -e "unix\n linux" > testfile` your one-liner reports 3 words.

Comment: Your timings show that wc is quicker (it's user and sys times that matter there). With LC_ALL=C, `wc` will be significantly quicker, just like with `PERLIO=:utf8`, `perl` will be significantly slower.

Comment: And no, `wc` doesn't load the entire file in memory before starting counting (easily checked with `yes | wc -w` not using up any memory). `perl` would have the issue though if the file was just one big line.

Comment: is there a similar way for wc -l ?

Comment: Using Perl's autosplit seemed significantly slower: $ time perl -lane '$word += scalar(@F); END {print $word}' lotofwords.txt   (lotofwords.txt had 200,000+ words)

Answer (score 3):

### Let's use AWK!

```bsh
$ function wordfrequency() { awk 'BEGIN { FS="[^a-zA-Z]+" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { word = tolower($i) words[word]++ } } END { for (w in words) printf("%3d %s\n", words[w], w) } ' | sort -rn } 
$ cat your_file.txt | wordfrequency
```

**This lists the frequency of each word occurring in the provided file.** I know it's not what you asked for, but it's better! If you want to see the occurrences of your word, you can just do this:

```bsh
$ cat your_file.txt | wordfrequency | grep yourword
```

I even added this function to my ***.dotfiles***

---

*Source: [AWK-ward Ruby](http://tomayko.com/writings/awkward-ruby)*

Comment: It counts words, so it is good enough for me! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `wc` program counts "words", but those are not for instance the "words" that many people would see when they examine a file.  The `vi` program for instance uses a different measure of "words", delimiting them based on their character classes, while `wc` simply counts things [separated by whitespace](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html).  The two measures can be radically different.  Consider this example:

```
first,second
```

`vi` sees **three** words (*first* and *second* as well as the comma separating them), while `wc` sees **one** (there is no whitespace on that line).  There are many ways to count words, some are less useful than others.

While Perl would be better suited to writing a counter for the vi-style words, here is a quick example using `sed`, `tr` and `wc` (moderately portable using literal carriage returns `^M`):

```
#!/bin/sh
in_words="[[:alnum:]_]"
in_punct="[][{}\\|:\"';<>,./?\`~!@#$%^&*()+=-]"
sed     -e "s/\($in_words\)\($in_punct\)/\1^M\2/g" \
        -e "s/\($in_punct\)\($in_words\)/\1^M\2/g" \
        -e "s/[[:space:]]/^M/g" \
        "$@" |
tr '\r' '\n' |
sed     -e '/^$/d' |
wc      -l
```

Comparing counts:

- Running the script on itself, gives me 76 words.
- The example in Perl by @cuonglm gives 31.
- Using `wc` gives 28.

For reference, [POSIX vi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) says:

> In the POSIX locale, vi shall recognize five kinds of words:
>
> 1. A maximal sequence of letters, digits, and underscores, delimited at both ends by:
>
>    - Characters other than letters, digits, or underscores
>    - The beginning or end of a line
>    - The beginning or end of the edit buffer
> 2. A maximal sequence of characters other than letters, digits, underscores, or  characters, delimited at both ends by:
>
>    - A letter, digit, underscore
>    - *`<blank>`* characters
>    - The beginning or end of a line
>    - The beginning or end of the edit buffer
> 3. One or more sequential blank lines
> 4. The first character in the edit buffer
> 5. The last non-*`<newline>`* in the edit buffer