# How can I find the number of instances of each text?

Tags: linux, text-processing

So I have a large file which is in a columns comprised of cities. I want to write a program that will find the total number of instances of each city and display it in a new file. How should I go about doing that.

*This is an example, there are way more values than this*

If the file is like this

```
City           
Manhattan   
Cork       
Manhattan  
Chennai
Chennai
```

How output should look

```
City
Manhattan 2 
Cork      1
Chennai   2
```

Comment: Looks like homework. See `uniq -c` after a `sort`.

Comment: See these: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479/find-n-most-frequent-words-in-a-file/174421#174421 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434860/trying-to-find-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file-using-a-script https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322909/word-frequency-gawk-memory-leak https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62056/whats-the-easiest-way-to-make-a-list-of-most-common-words-in-a-list?noredirect=1&lq=1  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80017/how-to-count-total-number-of-words-in-a-file

Comment: your question is an easier version of the duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Do it with `datamash`:

```
datamash -g1 -s -H count 1 < infile
```

Output:

```
GroupBy(City)   count(City)
Chennai 2
Cork    1
Manhattan   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linux built-in commands `sort` and `uniq`:

```
cat DATAFILE | sort | uniq --count
```

This will give you something like:

```
  2 Chennai
  1 City           
  1 Cork       
  2 Manhattan
```

**Explanation:** This uses the command `uniq` which normally removes repeated lines, keeping only one instance.  With the option "--count" it issues an additional count of the number of repetitions.  In order for `uniq` to work, lines need to be sorted - otherwise duplicates would not be in consecutive lines as necessary.  `sort` does exactly that, sort lines by alphabet.

Do you need these in a different column order?  Does the first line have to be ignored? If so, please also let us know whether city names may have more than one word in them.